# (Reopened) Reopen the question on owner ignoring sexual harassment complaints?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

This question [What can I do if the company owner dismisses my sexual harassment complaint?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/107229/3192) was closed as "unclear what you're asking". I edited the question to break the wall of text into paragraphs, and removed some irrelevant details to focus on an addressable goal.

Please cast reopen votes if this question is now good enough, or consider editing to further improve it.

Comment: I cast the last reopen vote.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like my own reopen vote expired, by the time I could solicit reopen votes here. Never mind that. :)

Comment: Still looking for that canonical post on dealing with harassment, that this would also be a duplicate of...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been reopened.